# How can I change the extension of files of a type using "find" with Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

The user inputs a file type they are looking for; it is stored in `$arg1`; the file type they would like to change them is stored as `$arg2`. I'm able to find what I'm looking for, but I'm unsure of how to keep the filename the same but just change the type... ie., `file1.txt` into `file1.log`.

```
find . -type f  -iname "*.$arg1" -exec mv {} \;
```

Comment: @Kenavoz The alleged duplicate deals with files in one directory only. I'm pretty sure there *is* a duplicate somewhere, but I can't find it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining the `find -exec bash` idea with the `bash` loop idea, you can use the `+` terminator on the `-exec` to tell `find` to pass multiple filenames to a single invocation of the bash command.  Pass the new type as the first argument - which shows up in `$0` and so is conveniently skipped by a `for` loop over the rest of the command-line arguments - and you have a pretty efficient solution:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.$arg1" -exec bash -c \
  'for arg; do mv "$arg" "${arg%.*}.$0"; done' "$arg2" {} +
```

Alternatively, if you have either version of the Linux `rename` command, you can use that. The Perl one (a.k.a. `prename`, installed by default on Ubuntu and other Debian-based distributions; also available for OS X from Homebrew via `brew install rename`) can be used like this:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.$arg1" -exec rename 's/\Q'"$arg1"'\E$/'"$arg2"'/' {} +
```

That looks a bit ugly, but it's really just the `s/old/new/` substitution command familiar from many UNIX tools. The `\Q` and `\E` around `$arg1` keep any weird characters inside the suffix from being interpreted as regular expression metacharacters that might match something unexpected; the `$` after the `\E` makes sure the pattern only matches at the end of the filename.

The pattern-based version installed by default on Red Hat-based Linux distros (Fedora, CentOS, etc) is simpler:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.$arg1" -exec rename ".$arg1" ".$arg2" {} +
```

but it's also dumber: if you `rename .com .exe stackoverflow.com_scanner.com`, you'll get a file named `stackoverflow.exe_scanner.exe`.

Answer (score 4):

To enable the full power of [shell parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), you can call `bash -c` in your `exec` action:

```sh
find . -type f -iname "*.$arg1" \
    -exec bash -c 'echo mv "$1" "${1/%.*/$1}"' _ {} "$arg2" \;
```

We add `{}` and `"$arg2"` as a parameters to `bash -c`, so they become accessible within the command as `$0` and `$1`. `${0%.*}` removes the extension, to be replaced by whatever `$arg2` expands to.

As it is, the command just prints the `mv` commands it would execute; to actually rename the files, the `echo` has to be removed.

The quoting is relevant: the argument to `bash -c` is in single quotes to prevent `$0` and `$1` from being expanded prematurely, and the two arguments to `mv`, and `arg2` are also quoted to deal with file names with spaces in them.

Comment: Could there be ref. to what the `_` is in this case? is it [this parameter from the shell expansions page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005f)?

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like so:

```
find . -type f  -iname "*.$arg1" -print0 |\
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
        mv -- "$file" "${file%$arg1}$arg2"
    done
```

I took your `find` command and fed its output to a `while` loop. Within that loop, I am doing the actual renaming. This way I have the name of the file as a variable that I can manipulate using bash's string manipulation operations.

Comment: You are much appreciated. Trying to learn this bash stuff and it's kicking my butt. Thanks

Comment: FWIW, you don't need the backslash; if a line ends with a pipe, the pipeline automatically continues on the next line with no need to escape the newline.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `perl` based `rename` command

Sample directory:

```
$ find
.
./a"bn.txt
./t2.abc
./abc
./abc/t1.txt
./abc/list.txt
./a bc.txt
```

Sample args:

```
$ arg1='txt'
$ arg2='log'
```

Dry run:

```
$ find -type f -iname "*.$arg1" -exec rename -n "s/$arg1$/$arg2/" {} +
rename(./a"bn.txt, ./a"bn.log)
rename(./abc/t1.txt, ./abc/t1.log)
rename(./abc/list.txt, ./abc/list.log)
rename(./a bc.txt, ./a bc.log)
```

Remove `-n` option once it is okay:

```
$ find -type f -iname "*.$arg1" -exec rename "s/$arg1$/$arg2/" {} +
$ find
.
./a bc.log
./t2.abc
./abc
./abc/list.log
./abc/t1.log
./a"bn.log
```